# Check if an element has no class specified

Tags: jquery, class, exists

I want to check if an element has a class specified or not (without knowing the class).  For example, given:

```
<div id="ball" class="dd">
```

and:

```
<div id="ball">
```

I want to check if it has no class at all.

I know there is a function called `hasClass` but this requires the class name to work.

## EDIT

The question was answered in that other post.
The answer which I found most useful was this:

```
$("#mydiv").prop('classList').length
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna check if the element has any class at all, you can check using the `.attr()` property:

```
$(element).attr("class").trim().length == 0
```

This handles a case like this too:

```
<div class=""></div>
```

You can also try to create a `hasAttr()` function this way:

```
var attr = $(this).attr('name');

// For some browsers, `attr` is undefined; for others, `attr` is false. Check for both.
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
  // Element has this attribute
}
```

More information about creating `.hasAttr()` at [A jQuery `hasAttr()` Equivalent](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-an-jquery-hasattr/).

Comment: I tried $(element).attr("class").trim().length==0 but kept getting the error TypeError: S()attrr is undefined. So that doesn't work if you have no class at all.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Did you see the second one, which has `hasAttr()` and stuff? You need to use the `typeof` code for checking `undefined`. Try it out.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach (if you consider elements with empty classes - like `<div class=""></div>` - as classful elements):

```
$('#ball').is('[class]');
```

It's more direct than checking class attribute value. In fact, you don't even need jQuery to do this:

```
document.getElementById('ball').hasAttribute('class');
```

---

Yet another option is using `classList`. [This API is tremendously useful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) (however, it's not supported in IE9-). `classList` returns `DOMTokenList`, an array-like object; the point is, if the class attribute was not set or is empty, its length is 0:

```
document.getElementById('ball').classList.length === 0;
```

Comment: I believe this might fail for `<div class="">`, doesn't it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar You are correct, made same error few time ago :)

Comment: It shows `true` for such an element, but I thought that's the OP's intent. If not, yes, it's better to compare class value with empty string, as in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<div id="ball" class="dd">
<div id="ball">

if ($('div').attr('class') != undefined){
        alert('YES');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var attr = $(this).attr('class');
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {

}
```

Comment: Isn't this like the same copy of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35176109)?